# Как правильно определить моноид собственного типа в cats?

Tags: gradle, scala

У меня есть такой вот код:

```
import cats.kernel.Monoid
import cats.syntax.monoid._

import cats.instances.int._

case class Order(totalCost: Double, quantity: Double)

class SuperAdder {
  import SuperAdder._

  def add(items: List[Int]): Int = items match {
    case x::xs => x |+| add(xs)
    case _ => Monoid[Int].empty
  }

  def addOrders(items: List[Order]): Order =
    items.foldRight(Monoid[Order].empty) (_ |+| _)
}

object SuperAdder {
  def apply: SuperAdder = new SuperAdder()

  implicit val monoidOrder: Monoid[Order] = new Monoid[Order] {
    override def empty: Order = Order(0, 0)

    override def combine(x: Order, y: Order): Order = Order(
      totalCost = x.totalCost + y.totalCost,
      quantity = x.quantity + y.quantity
    )
  }
}

object SuperAdderExercise extends App {
  println(new SuperAdder().add(1::2::3::4::Nil))
  println(new SuperAdder().addOrders(
    List(Order(1, 1), Order (1, 2), Order (2, 1))
  ))
}
```

Первый `println` отрабатывает правильно. На втором возникает такая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cats.kernel.Semigroup.$init$(Lcats/kernel/Semigroup;)V
```

Не понимаю, что не так с полугруппой.

Comment: Оба `println` работают. В зависимостях `"cats-core"  % "1.2.0"`. У тебя ошибка в IDEA или через `sbt` тоже?

Comment: @EnverOsmanov у меня `gradle` :)